# To get value of user input from input

Tags: javascript, dom, user-input

I am learning Javascript and trying to get user input value from input.

In my project, I have an input form, and when they add new number and click a button, and new form will appear, and user can put another number, and new input field will continue appearing as long as user clicks button.

What I want is to get value from each input. 
I saw some questions asking similar question, but .document.getElementsByName() didn't work for me.

```
let userInput = document.getElementsByName('moneyamount');
inputNum = parseInt(userInput.value);

console.log(inputNum); //result is NaN
```

I also tried document.querySelector()

```
let userInput = document.querySelector('#money-amount');
inputNum = parseInt(userInput.value);

console.log(inputNum)
```

which worked perfect, but I need to get value from a few inputs, so querySelector will not be good for this situation. 
so I tried document.querySelectorAll() as well, however,

```
let userInput = document.querySelectorAll('#money-amount');
inputNum = parseInt(userInput.value)

console.log(inputNum)// result is NaN
```

I am not sure what DOM I should use in this situation.
I need to select all elements and need to get value from them.

This is my HTML of input. There is only one input at this moment, because when user clicks add button, new form will be added.

```
          <input
            class="input money"
            type="number"
            id="money-amount"
            placeholder="Enter amount"
            name="moneyamount"
            required
          />

      </div>
```

I hope you guys could help this problem.

Thank you so much!

Comment: In your question you mention that users can click to add new input fields onto the page: but you never mention how you want to retrieve the value. Is it when a user clicks on a button? When a user defocuses from a field? There must be some sort of trigger. Also, can you share a code snippet where you have a functional prototype of new inputs being added? I have a feeling that there are multiple issues in your code and it's not all listed here in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the best way for you to handle this is to edit the innerHTML of the div.

for example:

```
<div id="allTheForms">
    <form action="#" onsubmit="addForm();">
      <input type="text">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button </form>
</div>
<script>
    function addForm() {
    var currentHTML = document.getElementById("allTheForms").innerHTML;
    var newForm = '<form action="#" onsubmit="addForm();"><input type="text"><button type="submit">Submit</button</form>';
    document.getElementById("allTheForms").innerHTML = currentHTML + newForm;
   }
</script>
```

This should allow you to do what I think you are asking.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. But my question is how to get value from user input.

Comment: For example, if they put 3 in input, I wanna extract that number on js,

Comment: Fortunately I know how to add new form. Please lemme know if you know how to extract the value from user input :))

Answer (score 0):

You could do `document.getElementById("money-amount").value` to get the amount from the input. If you are asking for values from multiple inputs you should do.

```
var userinputs = [];
function getInputs() {
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("input money");
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
if (typeof elem[i].value !== "undefined") {
userinputs.push(elem[i].value);
}
}
}
```

Then to access the first amount, you could do `userinputs[0]`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<input type='text' required id='input' onchange="check()">
<p id='output'>null</p>


<!-- the javascript -->
<script type='text/javascript'>

function check(){
//set the value as a let
let input = document.querySelector('#input').value;
//show it
document.querySelector('#output').textContent = input;

}
</script>
```